# Radiant heating with metal rods

Tags: heat

Can you run some sort of metal rod through your cement floor and connect that rod to a fireplace so when u use the fireplace it heats the rod and heats your house is that possible?

Comment: I don't think a solid rod would work because it wouldn't transfer the heat very far. A thin tube of copper with a blower circulating hot air or a pump circulating hot water heated  from the fireplace would work a little but you'd need to keep the fireplace going for a long time.

Comment: if you use hollow rods an pump hot water (heated by the fire) through them it will work

Answer (score 4):

You **can do** whatever you like.

How **well it works** may vary drastically.

In this case, the odds are that it will work very poorly. More functional options tend to be a bit more complex and involve circulating fluids that are warmed by the combustion source through the slab in pipes. Direct conduction becomes very ineffective when distances are long.